# Drawing 3D bar graphs using PHP?

Tags: php, charts

I'm looking to draw a 3d bar graph similar to the one below

[alt text http://techportal.co.za/article_images/image004.png](http://techportal.co.za/article_images/image004.png)

My problem is that I can't seem to find any useful library that can do this for me, any classes available that can do this for me. I tried pchart but this does not seem to work for this, only for 3d pie charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe here you can find something suitable?
http://jpgraph.net/features/gallery.php#bar1

Comment: But if I were to do it today, I would certainly not use PHP, but I would do it in JavaScript, taking data via JSON from PHP. See ChartJS or any other one. This is much better because you don't to graphics on the server side, you can make it responsive, etc... JPgraph can still be very useful if you have to generate PDFs server side, for example.

Comment: You know what I dislike about JavaScript? That large dynamic content never loads on slow mobile connections. For example, when I'm in the countryside, messages on Facebook never load for me and I abandoned FB because of that. They must think everyone lives close to a mobile antenna. Server side content, on the other hand, always loads. Therefore I don't use JS on essential content.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use PHP for the graphs to ensure that everyone who views the site can see them? Why not use a JS library such as [Plotr](http://solutoire.com/plotr/) to create the spangly 3D version, but fall back on CSS for those users without the correct browser support;

http://speckyboy.com/2009/02/04/16-usable-css-graph-and-bar-chart-tutorials-and-techniques/

**EDIT**

If the graph is being sent via email then you can't use JS, but there's no reason why you can't use CSS. Get PHP to output a list, or a series of inputs (whatever best fit's your purpose), send the email in an HTML format, and use CSS to style the HMTL using one of the techniques illustrated in the link above.

Also, using PHP to generate static images will present other issues, most notably getting through user's spam filters and your own bandwidth, not to mention how much of a waste of CPU cycles it is to process these images when a bit of HTML / CSS trickery would achieve the same effect.

Comment: I need to use PHP, since this script isn't going to run in a browser, accessing it via the command line and then mailing users with there stats in a graph

Comment: Ahh, OK. That's pretty important, might be worth adding that to the question so people can help in a more specific way. I'll make a edit to my answer above...